# About obj files to export with textures

Tags: texturing, materials, export, import, obj

How to import a wavefront obj file with textures without having the mtl files as I have downloaded a model but it does not contains the mtl files it have only the textures and obj.

Comment: create a valid text mtl file by looking at examples.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very simple, since OBJ files carry their own UV maps. After importing the model, create materials for it like you normally would if you had made the model in Blender and already created the UV map, then import your textures into the materials manually with Image Texture nodes.